# how to upload jpegs with their metadata to mysql column

Tags: php

I was trying to write a PHP code that uploads all images to mysql db and shows the images metadata in columns. in my code it uploads the images but does not show the metadata. for example I tried to insert the width of the image, I made a column for that and when I upload the image the width is always 0. can someone check my code and help me find a solution for than?

```
<?php 
// Include the database configuration file 
include_once 'dbconfig.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // File upload configuration 
    $targetDir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\uploaded\\"; 
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif'); 

    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = ''; 
    $fileNames = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']); 
    
    if(!empty($fileNames)){
    
        function getExif( $filename, $key1, $key2) {
            $width = 0;
            $allowedFiletypes = array("jpg","jpeg","tif","tiff");
            if(in_array(strtolower(substr($filename, -3)),$allowedFiletypes)) {
                if(exif_read_data($filename) == true) {
                    $exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

                    foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
                        foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
                            if($key === $key1 AND $name === $key2){
                                $width = $val;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    return $width;
            } else {
                print "filetype not supported";
            }
        }

        $key1 = "IFD0";
        $key2 = "ImageWidth";

        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
            // File upload path 
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]); 
            $width = getExif( $fileName, $key1, $key2);

            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName; 
            // Check whether file type is valid 
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Upload file to server 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){ 
                    // Image db insert sql 
                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW(), '".$width."'),"; 
                }else{ 
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
                } 
            }else{ 
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
            } 
        }
        
        // Error message 
        $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.trim($errorUpload, ' | '):''; 
        $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.trim($errorUploadType, '    | '):''; 
        $errorMsg =      !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType; 

        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL, ','); 
            
            // Insert image file name into database 
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images(file_name, uploaded_on, image_width) VALUES      $insertValuesSQL"); 
            if($insert){ 
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg; 
            }else{ 
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = "Upload failed! ".$errorMsg; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
    }
}

?>
    <form action="upload1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select Image Files to Upload:
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
    </form>
```

my goal is to upload images with all their metadata

Comment: While it is legal to declare functions in an IF block it is rarely sensible

Comment: `$_FILES['files']['name']` contains the original name of the file on the client machine, not the uploaded file, you'll find that in `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]`.

Comment: Well if you were to actually look at the contents of the IFD0 section, there is no `ImageWidth` property in there

Comment: And to actually find the _temp_ file, you should probably not apply `basename` first either.

Comment: You want to walk through the array of files. So you do `foreach ($_FILES['files']`, and not `foreach ($_FILES['files']['name']`.

Comment: And as @KIKOSoftware says the filename of the file you want to look at is in `$fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]); `

Comment: In the `COMPUTED` section there are `Height` and `Width` values

Comment: Seems to me you would benefit from running your development with [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) **turned on** Add to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing in the filename rather than the file itself - and a name does not have any EXIF data attributes. One other issue that you will encounter with EXIF perhaps is that not every camera adds the same details so there ar eno guarantees that a particular property will exist within a particular section so forking the processing logic around that is needed.

You can simplify the `getExif` function using `array_key_exists` rather than the nested loops which can be prone to issues. For example, a `bare-bones` piece of PHP without the SQL portion.

The `getExif` below either returns exactly the item requested or the entire exif response which can be used to fork the logic as mentioned. In testing I found just one image that contained both the section and required parameter ($key1,$key2- renamed for clarity)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select Image Files to Upload:
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form> 
        <?php

            error_reporting( E_ALL );
            ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
            
            
            
            function uploaderror( $error ){ 
                switch( $error ) { 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                    default: return "Unknown upload error";
                }
            }
            function getExif( $filename, $section=false, $param=false ) {
                if( $section & $param ){
                    
                    $exif = @exif_read_data( $filename,0, true );
                    if( array_key_exists( $section, $exif ) && array_key_exists( $param, $exif[ $section ] ) )return $exif[ $section ][ $param ];
                    
                    return $exif;
                }
                return false;
            }

            
            
            
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES['files'] ) ){
                
                $exts = array('jpg','jpeg','tif','tiff');
                $files=(object)$_FILES['files'];
                
                foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
                    $name = $files->name[$i];
                    $size = $files->size[$i];
                    $type = $files->type[$i];
                    $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
                    $error= $files->error[$i];
                    $errors=array();
                    
                    if( !$error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )$errors[]=uploaderror( $error );
                    
                    if( empty( $errors )){
                        
                        $ext = strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                        $targetDir = __DIR__ . '/uploads';
                        $targetFile = sprintf('%s/%s',$targetDir,$name);
                        
                        if( in_array( $ext, $exts )){
                            
                            /*
                                What you wish to find in the exif...
                            */
                            $section = "IFD0";
                            $param = "ImageWidth";
                            /*
                                find and process...
                            */
                            $result = getExif( $tmp, $section, $param );
                            
                            
                            if( !is_numeric( $result ) or is_array( $result ) ){
                                $errors[]=sprintf('Unable to locate property "%s" within designated section: "%s"',$param,$section);
                                $errors[]=$result;
                            }else{
                                
                                # just to show the data...
                                printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $result, true ) );
                                
                                
                                /*
                                    save file to disk...
                                */
                                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetFile );
                                if( !$status )$errors[]='Failed to save file';
                                
                                /*
                                    sql... use a Prepared Statement!
                                */
                                $sql='insert into images( `file_name`, `uploaded_on`, `image_width` ) values (?,?,?)';
                                /*
                                $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
                                $args=array(
                                    $name,
                                    date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                    $result
                                );
                                $stmt->bind_param('sss',...$args);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                */
                            }
                        }else{
                            $errors[]='unknown file extension: '.$ext;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if( !empty( $errors ) )printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($errors,true));
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! you answered my question. i want to ask you another thing now, lets say i need to upload 1000 images, and eventually i want to choose only the images that contains lets say "date taken" for example and all images that taken at this date will show up. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Essentially yes I see no reason why you cannot do that - you can analyse the exif data in whatever way you need - perhaps you setup an array of sections/tags to parse.  The above was only a quick example - it could be better structured and additional logic incorporated

Comment: perhaps worth noting is that `if( !is_numeric( $result ) or is_array( $result ) ){` is really intended as the tests for a `width` as per the question. That logic test would not work if you were seeking other types of data from the exif response ...

Comment: i was trying to upload the images to the database but i can find a way, I was tryng to add a code to upload to sql but i just show the metadata in the web and did not upload any images. can you help me with that?

Comment: The above code has sql to add each uploaded file to a db table. I have not tested that but it is there commented out. Have you uncommented it and tried?

Comment: yes i tried to uncomment it but it does not work for me

Comment: I have just tested that functionality - it took ages to find a photo that contained the correct exif data but worked OK when I finally did and inserted the record OK. If this does not work for you are you certain that the images you are testing with contain that exif data? Have you enabled error reporting? Do the files get uploaded?

Comment: i have a photo with the exif data, when i press submit it display the meta data but does not upload it to mysql db, and i have no error

Comment: how have you tried debugging this so far? Does the folder exist where the images are to be stored? Does the program reach the SQL portion and stop? Does it go beyond the sql? Use echo statements to test the paths and stages etc. The problem lies in your implementation of the code - is it identical to the above?

Comment: i will try using echo now and be back with the answer, thank you!